# PHP - Как проверить доступен ли сайт и в случае если он не отвечает то заменить ссылку-редирект взяв еë из списка ссылок

Tags: php

Есть index.php с редиректом , но ссылка на которую он редиректит часто отваливаеться на несколько часов,что несёт за собой потери средств за рекламу. Можно ли как-то сделать чтобы в случае если сайт не отвечает то заманить ссылку в index.php выбрав еë из списка ссылок которые,я укажу? Спасибо

Comment: можно в фоне опрашивать раз в N минут, например, доступность ресурса. Или перед каждым редиректом ходить проверять самому, потом редиректить, но эт такой себе вариант, кажется (увеличите трафик, увеличите время отклика, нет гарантий что у юзера адрес окажется доступен). В целом тут нужен HEAD запрос. Или комбинированный варинат, при редиректе сходили проверили, сохранили состояние, редиректнули. В следующий раз сначала проверили состояние, и если проверка была недавно, то сразу редирект, если нет, то пять проверка, сохранение, редирект.

Comment: Именно задача такая: зашел на сайт - сайт не доступен происходит автозамена ссылки в коде либо какой-то перебор по листу ссылок пока ответ сервера не будет позитивным, не подскажите как такое сделать?